# Django 2.0 Operational Error: cursor "_django_curs_139683611834112_1" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django

the sub-header for the error is:

"Error during template rendering

In .../base.html error at line 0

cursor  "_django_curs_139683611834112_1" does not exist

Currently using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6 on a server running Ubuntu with docker. The error occurs when loading a blank URL through the stream below:

urls.py:

```
from dashboard2.account_views_new import AccountView

'''urlpatterns =             [                                  
    url(r'^$', AccountView.as_view(), name='home'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views:

```
class AccountView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'fv1/dash_nav.html'

    def get(self, request):
        this_form = forms.ThisForm()
        that_form = forms.ThatForm()
        forms = Form.objects.all()
        things = Things.objects.all()

        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):
   
        this = that1.objects.all()
        that = this1.objects.all()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {data})
```

base.html (error is thrown at line 0):

```
<!-- update this to include headers and such in jynja -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{%  load static %}
<head>
```

what is producing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this problem

1. Backup Your DB
2. Delete All files in all app migration folder (Except _ _ init _ _ .py)
3. If use Docker Delete DB Volumes, **Else**  Delete Your DB
4. ReCreate the Database
5. Run `$Python manage.py makemigrations`
6. Run `$Python manage.py migrate`
7. Restore Your DB Backup
8. Enjoy IT